# What could cause a VirtualBox guest to enter a VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE

Tags: virtualbox

I'm running several VirtualBox servers on CentOS, with multiple Virtualbox guests on each.

Once every few days/weeks, I'd have a guest stop responding, and though it shows as *running*, it is actually in a VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE, and only the following will abort it:

```
VBoxManage startvm "<guest-name>" --type emergencystop
```

I'm trying to determing the cause for my guest machines entering VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE.

**Are there any known situations that will cause a guest machine to enter VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE, or can you suggest ways to debug this issue?**

Comment: `VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE` is caused by any number of conditions.  Other then forcefully turning the virtual machine off what have you tried?

Comment: Nothing other than `VBoxManage startvm "<guest-name>" --type emergencystop` seems to work. E.g., `$ VBoxManage controlvm "main-direct-ingest-vb-maor" poweroff                                                                                                                                    
VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine is being powered down
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_VM_STATE (0x80bb0002), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "PowerDown(progress.asOutParam())" at line 577 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp
`